# How to split hours in Time Range in C#?

Tags: time, split, range

start time `13:00`
End time `17:00`

get all hours and put to array

> output arrHrs = {"13","14","15","16","17"}

Answer (score 0):

```
var startTime = 13, endTime = 17;
var arrHrs = new List<int>();
while(startTime <= endTime)
{
   arrHrs.Add(startTime++);
}
```

OR in an easier way

```
var startTime = 13, endTime = 17;
var arrHrs = Enumerable.Range(startTime, endTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try something like that

```
DateTime startTime = Convert.ToDateTime("01-01-2013 20:00");
DateTime endTime = Convert.ToDateTime("01-02-2013 02:00");
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
list = Listhours(startTime, endTime);
```

Need to create a function like

```
private List<DateTime> Listhours(DateTime starttm, DateTime endtm)
    {
        var Listhour = new List<DateTime>();

        DateTime startt = Convert.ToDateTime(starttm.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00"));
        DateTime endd = Convert.ToDateTime(endtm.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:00:00"));

        for (double dblDate = startt.ToOADate();
             dblDate <= endd.ToOADate();
             dblDate += (1.0 / 24.0))
        {
            Listhour.Add(DateTime.FromOADate(dblDate));
        }

        return Listhour;
    }
```

Hope it works.